# error in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core

Was trying to follow a tutorial here for a console app https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-and-read-connection-string-in-appsettings-json/

So in my appsettings-json i have:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDb1": "Server=myServer;Database=myDb1;Trusted_Connection=True;",
  }
}
```

My program:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace mynamespace 
{
    class Program
    {
        string myDb1ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("myDb1");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is : "The name '_configuration' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: That's not a tutorial, in any way. It assumes you already have a working, configured .NET application and just want to read a string from configuration. In a .NET 6 project you wouldn't be able to use such code at all, as `Configuration` would be available through the host object. What kind of application are you building? Web app? Console application? Which .NET version?

Comment: You need to create a `ConfigurationBuilder`, load the file `appsettings.json` with extension Method `AddJsonFile` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` and then call `Build()` on the `ConfigurationBuilder`. Then you have a `Configuration` object from which you can load the connection string.

Comment: @Hazrelle in .NET Core 3 and later simply creating a generic host takes care of all of this.

Comment: Check [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) to understand how configuration really works.

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos but no host was specified and the OP may want to do it manually. In .NET 6 a minimal Console Application has no host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to isn't a tutorial, it only shows how to read a connection string from *any configuration provider*, not just appsettings.json. It assumes you've already built a configuration object. .NET (Core) 5 and 6 use far simpler code though.

Check [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) to understand how configuration really works. You can find more detailed information on the various config providers, how they're used and how to create your own in [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**Using a generic host**

In .NET 6, the current long term version, a minimal application would need:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();


var configuration=host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

var connectionString=configuration.GetConnectionString("blahblah");

...
```

As the docs explain, `CreateDefaultBuilder` will load configuration settings from any appsettings.json files, environment variables and finally command-line parameters.

This means you can override the settings stored in the JSON files by specifying the new values using environment variables or CLI parameters, eg :

```
dotnet run /ConnectionStrings:blahblah="......."
```

**Without a generic host**

You can create just the Configuration object by using a ConfigurationBuilder:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

var connectionString=config.GetConnectionString("blahblah");
```